# XPath select child node based on multy child nodes attributes

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<NETCAST>
    <ACTION NParam="7" ShortName="shot" Quarter="1" Position="27">
        <PARAM Data="2" Name="Team"/>
        <PARAM Data="2" Name="Player"/>
        <PARAM Data="0" Name="Made"/>
        <PARAM Data="2" Name="Points"/>
        <PARAM Data="1" Name="AddFlags"/>
    </ACTION>
    <ACTION NParam="2" ShortName="assist" Quarter="1" Position="28">
        <PARAM Data="2" Name="Team"/>
        <PARAM Data="21" Name="Player"/>
    </ACTION>
    <ACTION NParam="7" ShortName="shot" Quarter="1" Position="29">
        <PARAM Data="1" Name="Team"/>
        <PARAM Data="21" Name="Player"/>
        <PARAM Data="0" Name="Made"/>
        <PARAM Data="3" Name="Points"/>
        <PARAM Data="0" Name="AddFlags"/>
    </ACTION>
    <ACTION NParam="7" ShortName="shot" Quarter="1" Position="30">
        <PARAM Data="2" Name="Team"/>
        <PARAM Data="32" Name="Player"/>
        <PARAM Data="0" Name="Made"/>
        <PARAM Data="3" Name="Points"/>
        <PARAM Data="4" Name="AddFlags"/>
    </ACTION>
    <ACTION NParam="3" ShortName="reb" Quarter="1" Position="31">
        <PARAM Data="1" Name="Team"/>
        <PARAM Data="-2" Name="Player"/>
        <PARAM Data="1" Name="Type"/>
    </ACTION>
    <ACTION NParam="7" ShortName="shot" Quarter="1" Position="32">
        <PARAM Data="1" Name="Team"/>
        <PARAM Data="15" Name="Player"/>
        <PARAM Data="1" Name="Made"/>
        <PARAM Data="2" Name="Points"/>
        <PARAM Data="3" Name="AddFlags"/>
    </ACTION>
</NETCAST>
```

I need help with the XPATH query in order to select

ACTION/PARAM[@Name="Points"]/Data (in order todo SUM)

Where

ACTION[NParam="7"] AND

ACTION/PARAM[@Name="Team"][Data="1"] AND

ACTION/PARAM[@Name="Made"][Data="0"] AND

ACTION/PARAM[@Name="AddFlags"][Data="1" or "3" or "4"]

I know how to select but using only one child!!!

```
/NETCAST/ACTION[NParam=7]/PARAM[@Name="Points"]/@Data
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear what is the expected output exactly. Assuming you want to find `ACTION` that match multiple criteria based on multiple `PARAM`'s attributes, you may want to follow XPath example below :

```
/NETCAST
/ACTION[
    @NParam=7 and
    PARAM[@Name="Team" and @Data="1"] and
    PARAM[@Name="Made" and @Data="0"] and
    PARAM[@Name="AddFlags"][@Data="0" or @Data="3" or @Data="4"]
]
```

**<kbd>[`xpath demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/o6X4ei3KK)</kbd>**

Given the XML in this question as input, the output would be :

```
<ACTION NParam="7" ShortName="shot" Quarter="1" Position="29">
   <PARAM Data="1" Name="Team"/>
   <PARAM Data="21" Name="Player"/>
   <PARAM Data="0" Name="Made"/>
   <PARAM Data="3" Name="Points"/>
   <PARAM Data="0" Name="AddFlags"/>
</ACTION>
```

Comment: The Xpath that you suggest is OK for the query, but the results that I need is to get is not the entire ACTION node. I need only the <PARAM Data="3" Name="Points"/> for the above result. Using your answer +  /PARAM[@Name="Points"], I got it. Thanks for your accurate and quick response.